# iOS Integrate push notification in library

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, static-libraries

I am developing a static library with some common classes which can be used in multiple applications.

This common code performs certain action on receiving Push Notification.
Can I add push notification module *(registering for push,receiving push and handling push)* in library?

Will the application which uses this library receive push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add the registration and handling part in your library, the registration method of library should be called  in below mentioned method of AppDelegate

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

and the necessary push notification delegate methods should be implemented in your apps AppDelegate class.  And from AppDelegate class you can redirect them(receiving push and handling push) to your library.

Will the application which uses this library receive push notification?

For this you have to enable the `Push Notification` to your app ID and generate the Development SSL Certificate/Production SSL Certificate accordingly. These SSL certificates should be generated separately for each app where you intend to use your library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I will try this way.

Comment: I tried your solution but I think by this way their will be a big issue:  Every application which will use this SDK has to share their certificates with the server who is sending notifications.
Is it really feasible to add Push Notification functionality in SDK?

Comment: Yes every app needs to have their own certificates, this what i mentioned in my comment. But this can be handled at server side.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your reply.